# What's the best way to implement django models for multiple choice against multiple strings

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.2

I'm working on a project using Django(2.2) and Python(3.7) in which I have to implement models for a specific scenrio:

I have a Vote in which we have five questions like:

```
DELIVERING VALUE
EASY TO RELEASE
FUN
HEALTH OF CODEBASE
TEAMWORK
```

and each of these questions has options in the form of dropdown as:
-- Select --
--helpful--
--not helpful--
--disaster--

and all of these votes will belong to a group and later I need to perform some aggregations to get the total no of votes for of these options (like helpful) against each question (like DELIVERING VALUE).

Here's how currently I have implemented this scenario in Django models:

**From `models.py`:**

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='notingroup')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group


VOTE_CHOICES = (
    ('helpful', "helpful"),
    ('meh', 'meh'),
    ('disaster', 'disaster')
)


class VotingValues(models.Model):
    value1 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    value2 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    value3 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    value4 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    value5 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    score1 = models.CharField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    score2 = models.CharField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    score3 = models.CharField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    score4 = models.CharField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    score5 = models.CharField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    user = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='notingroup')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user + ' \'s ' + 'vote in ' + self.group
```

is there a better approach to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't like puting the questions inside same model as answers. maybe it's better idea to put questions in another model (something like `Question`)

```
class Question(models.Model):
    q1 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    q2 = ...

class VotingValues(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    a1 = ...
```

I think this is cleaner compared to your solution, but you can think more about it. if it's just a one time thing above answer is good enough but if you might need to create more surveys with more or less questions it's clear that for each survey you need to change current models or create new ones

to solve this issue, first thing comes to my mind is putting questions and answers inside a json field or array field

```
class Question(models.Model):
    q = JSONField()

class VotingValues(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    a = JSONField()
```

(note that I don't know how aggregated queries work with json field so you might need to look it up)

other thing comes to my mind is instead of using json field add a new model to store individual questions:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField
    group = foreign key to question group

class QuestionGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField 

class Vote(models.Model):
    question = foreign key to question
    score = ...
```

for current survey: you create 1 `question_group` and add 5 `questions` for that group. when user votes for that `question_group` you add 5 rows in `vote` table (one row for each question in question group)

Comment: Question will be the same always and also the number of questions will remain 5 which I have mentioned above.

Comment: I really don't like putting questions in the same table as answers. move them outside to another table or simply discard them (show the questions in front-end but don't store them in db, just keep the answers)